# Numpy.where (ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, comparison

For my program I need a check comparison between an already existing DataFrame and a new DataFrame which comes as an input. The comparison should compare each cell of each DataFrame.
The case i need to find is, that in either the old and the new DataFrame there is a value but only if the value is different for this specific position it goes into a third reference DataFrame. The Reference DataFrame should e.g. like this:

```
     A    B
0    1  nan
1    2  nan
2  nan    3
3  nan    4

Input DataFrame
     A    B
0  nan    2
1    3    5
2    4    4
3  nan  nan

Reference DataFrame
   A  B
0  3  4
```

I figured the best way is to compare each column with np.where

Since both existing and input DataFrame can be different the challenge is, that this method can only compare identically-labeled.

therefore I excluded non sharing colums and sorted them in the same order. So all Column names are the same and in the same order

Also i used this loop to align the number of records of both DataFrames:

```
dfshape = df.shape[0]
df1shape = df1.shape[0]
    
      if dfshape < df1shape:
                while i < (df1shape - dfshape):
                    df = df.append(pd.Series(0, index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
                    i += 1
            else:
                while i < (dfshape - df1shape):
                    df1 = df1.append(pd.Series(0, index=df1.columns), ignore_index=True)
                    i += 1
```

Both DataFrames brought into the same shape I tried the following operation:

```
 for column in df1:
        for idx in df1.index:
            if df.loc[idx, column] is not None:
                 dfRefercence = np.where(df1[column] != df[column], df1.loc[idx, column])
```

But ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

At this point I've run out of idieas to takle this problem and also could not identify the cause of the thrown Exception.
Maybe there is another way to achieve the desired result?
pandas.DataFrame.compare seems not to do the trick for me with this problem:

```
df2 = df.compare(df1)

     A          B      
  self other self other
0    1   nan  nan     2
1    2     3  nan     5
2  nan     4    3     4
3  NaN   NaN    4   nan
```

Comment: Can you please shed some light on how `Reference Datframe` is like that?

Comment: Look at the arrays that `values` gives you.  Indices no longer apply.

Comment: @ashkangh the Reference Dataframe is how the result should look like as an example given. Cleared it up in my post.

Comment: @hpaulj so your mean something like                                                                       
 for column in df1:
    for idx in df1:
        if df1.values[column, idx] is not None and df1.values[column, idx] != df.values[column, idx]: dfReference = df1.values[column, idx]